# blur everything except a particular div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to blur the entire background once a div appeared. I have hidden the div and it will appear in button click. on that div appearance, the entire background should be blurred. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you have provided us with the code you are working with. Nonetheless, check the following out. It might help you.

You can do this using `backdrop-filter: blur()` instead of `filter: blur()` to make sure the elements behind the `.backdrop` are blurred, instead of the element itself.

I hope the code is self-explanatory (the complete code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nipunadodan/pen/RwByxbo)). But if you are wondering, it's just the `.backdrop` positioned over all the elements using `position: fixed;` and `z-index:9998;`. And then the `.except` is placed over the `.backdrop` using `z-index: 9999;` which is one level higher than the `.backdrop` but only using `position: relative;` so it's at the same place as it was before. You can position it wherever you want it to be.

**This way you can blur everything including the backgrounds except for the desired element and you don't need to reposition the `.except` element somewhere else this way if you don't want to.**

Let me know if you need more clarification.

```css
.except {
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9998;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    background: #33333377;
    backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">Some text</div>  
    <div class="content except">Some text</div>  
    <div class="content">Some text</div>
    <div class="content">Some text</div> 
</div>

<div class="backdrop"></div>
```

Demo with the complete code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nipunadodan/pen/RwByxbo)

Answer (score -2):

you could do the following

in your css

```css
.blur {
filter: blur(5px);

}
```

javascript file

```
document.querySelector("*").classList.add("blur");
document.querySelector("div_id").classList.remove("blur");
```